# How do I allow anonymous users to access an image?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, forms-authentication

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET website that uses `Forms Authentication` to restrict access to some files (`~/resources/restricted/*`) a user needs to register to see. Unfortunately, this has the extra effect of disallowing a background (`~/common/images/backgrounds/bg_community.jpg`) in an unrelated section of the website.

What is wrong with my configuration/how can I fix this?

#### ~/Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">

  <!-- ... --->

  <system.web>

    <!-- ... --->

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/users/login.aspx" />
    </authentication>

    <!-- ... --->

  </system.web>

  <!-- ... --->

  <location path="~/resources/restricted">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <!-- ... --->

</configuration>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just add another "location" section for the public image directory with an <allow users="*" /> ?  (But maybe you've already tried that.)

Comment: Well, I don't really want to have to do this for each directory. I'm looking for a solution that will only exclude the `~/resources/restricted` directory and leave the rest alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure for the path, I think that this would be enough:

```
path="resources/restricted"
```

In situations like this, I like to create additional web.config file located inside /resources/restricted/ folder. This way you can be sure which location you control. The downside is that you have more than one config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users ="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty easy way to handle it for the limited situation he's describing.